# Infinite series containing binomial coefficients

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-distributions, binomial-coefficients, random-walk

I've encountered the following series:

$$\sum_{t=1}^\infty {1 \over 2^{t}}\,
{{\large t} \choose {\large{t + x \over 2}}}$$

Is this series even convergent? I'm really lacking knowledge on series that contains binomial coefficients.

I actually encountered this series when calculating $E(T_x)$, where $T_x$ is the first time a random walker hits the disposition $x$. I'm also looking for other ways to get around this series via manipulation on expected value, but no clue yet..

Many thanks!

Comment: Have you tried [Stirling's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This diverges for all $x$. For $x=0$, Stirling's approximation gives us
$$2^{-t}\binom{t}{t/2}=\frac{t!}{2^t((t/2)!)^2}\sim \frac{\sqrt{2\pi t}t^te^{2\cdot t/2}}{2^t\cdot 2\pi (t/2)(t/2)^{2\cdot t/2}e^t}=\sqrt{2\pi/t}$$
and $\sum_{t=1}^\infty \sqrt{2\pi/t}=\infty$. Since 
$$P_x(t):=\frac{t+x}{2}!\frac{t-x}{2}!-((t/2)!)^2$$
is a polynomial in $t$, we have
$$\binom{t}{\frac{t+x}{2}}=\frac{t!}{\frac{t+x}{2}!\frac{t-x}{2}!}=\frac{t!}{((t/2)!)^2+P_x(t)}\sim \frac{t!}{((t/2)!)^2}=\binom{t}{t/2}$$
and so similarly the series diverges for all values of $x$.

Comment: Maybe, the OP omitted some other detail or/and the model has to be re-worked out.

Comment: This seems to work, and I believe the series diverges. Thank you @AlexBecker!

Comment: @FelixMarin what detail do you mean? How would they affect? Thx!